# AngularJS: Return function based on input type

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, input, scope

I have an input box in my HTML file. If the user inputs a number I would like to return getZip() and if the user inputs a string I would like to return getCity(). Is this possible to do with a single input box or would I need to have one designated for type="text" and one designated for type="number"?

view.html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <form ng-submit="getData()">
  <input type="search" ng-model="location">
  <button>Get Weather</button>
</form>
```

myApp.js:

1st attempt:

```
$scope.getData = function() {
  switch (angular.isString($scope.location)) {
    case true:
      return $scope.getCity();
      break;
    case false:
      return $scope.getZip();
      break;
    default:
      return "Location not recognized";
    };
  };
```

2nd attempt:

```
$scope.getData = function () {
  if (angular.isString($scope.location)) {
      return $scope.getCity() 
   } else {
      return $scope.getZip()
  };
```

It seems like even if the input is a number, once it is passed through the scope, it is a string no matter what. Is there a way around this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check whether or not your input is a number, since all input would be of type string initially:

```
if (!isNaN($scope.location)) {
    return $scope.getZip()
}
else {
    return $scope.getCity()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to compare the input to a numeric value, you should parse it to int:

```
if( !isNaN($scope.location) && parseInt($scope.location) == 1123) {
  alert('yes');
}
```

`isNaN()` return `true` if the input is NOT a number, that's why I added **!** to the condition

Answer (score 0):

try the other way, start with angular.isNumber a string number should return true but a string with letters should return false